# How add Pagination in Joomla2.5 in the module mod_articles_last?

Tags: joomla2.5, paging

I am using joomla2.5, and I want to add Pagination for the user checking the latest articles they publish after they login from front end.

Here is the folder structure:

```
   mod_articles_latest
    -- mod_articles_latest.xml
    -- mod_articles_latest.php
    -- index.html
    -- helper.php
    -- tmpl(folder)
       -- index.html
       -- default2.php
       -- default.php
```

Comment: Joomla provides pagination functions for components but they won't work with modules. You would be better off loading all the results and using buttons to hide/display a set of results in different div tags.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is possible to pagination outside a component, but there are other issues with paginating a module, like clicking next implies a page load.

These guys seem to know what they are asking about:

https://groups.google.com/forum/m/?fromgroups#!topic/joomla-dev-general/spjD7Oeixa0